# Shell programming temp=$1 vs temp=1

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

What's the difference between `temp=$1` and `temp=1`? Why do I need the dollar sign?

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=$1
cell=$((($temp-32)*5/9))

echo $cell
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 9):

The dollar-sign triggers [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion); `1` is the string `"1"`, while `$1` is the first shell parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[In addition to what [ruakh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12378/ruakh) had already mentioned]

Your script attempts to convert a temperature value from Fahrenheit to Celsius scale. You could save your file with a name say, `tocelsius.sh`. Now, you can convert any given temperature (in Fahrenheit scale) by passing a value to your script:

```
bash tocelsius.sh 66
```

When you do so, your `$1` would contain the value 66. Thus, you would get the corresponding output.

However, when you write `temp=1`, the variable `temp` will always take the fixed value 1. No argument passed to your script (as shown above) would be considered.

To conclude, `$xyz` points to the *value* of the variable `xyz`. `$1`, `$2`, ... are special cases where it points to the arguments passed from command line, if any.